# Report on child records and field in parent only once per child

Tags: reporting, master-detail

Say you have a structure like

Account 1, Annual revenue = 100,000

```
Contact 1


Contact 2
```

Account 2, Annual revenue = 200,000

```
Contact 3
```

Does anybody know if a report can be developed to show something like

Contact name      Account Name    Revenue

Contact 1         Account 1       100,000

Contact 2         Account 1

Contact 3         Account 2       200,000

i.e. show each contact but allow for sum of total revenue across all accounts (only counting revenue once per account)

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the purpose of the report? What is the relationship between the contacts and the revenue? I.e. now it looks a bit like the revenue belongs only to contact 1 and not to contact 2.